# Monitoring BATTERY_CHANGED with BroadcastReceiver and displaying with level-list not working

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android, battery

Hello everyone I've been stick with this problem, and I can't see my mistake. I had used  before basicly for having different drawable bind to a specific level, nevertheless I am trying to use it within a BroadcastReceiver wich monitor battery changes, the problem is that I don't get any UI update when I called the setImageLevel change?

The Broadcast Receiver goes like this

```
public class BatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG, "Fired Changed");
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 100);

        int percent = (level * 100) / scale;

        imageBattery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageBatery);
        imageBattery.setImageLevel(percent);
        Log.d(LOG, "On UI running I am");

        // imageBattery.getDrawable().mutate();
        // imageBattery.invalidate();

        // Log.d(LOG,"DRawable: "+((LevelListDrawable)imageBattery.getDrawable()).getCurrent());

    }

}
```

The Log gets displayed but it does not change my ImageView if you can point me out in the right direction, or you have any insight on this issue?

**Little bit of more info**

Here is my Registration and unregistration both on the same activity as the BroadcastReceiver

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

How do I instatiate the ImageView Drawable:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageBatery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/battery_status" />
```

And also battery_status.xml is a drawable (*I removed some of the drawable item because you get the idea I have from 0-100*)

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/stat_sys_battery_100"
    android:maxLevel="100"/>

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/stat_sys_battery_90"
    android:maxLevel="90"/>

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/stat_sys_battery_80"
    android:maxLevel="80"/>
```

Comment: what exactly do you use for `LevelListDrawable`? 
are all the images have different length?

Comment: no they all have the same size

Comment: and LevelListDrawable I use a drawable resource I just re-edit the question you can check battery_status.xml

Answer (score 0):

Do You have your `BroadcastReceiver` inlined in Your `Activity`? If so, use 'MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread()` method to change Your views.

Comment: I already try to used runOnUiThread() no luck... and yes I have my Broadcast inside the activity

Comment: Do You have reference to ImageView present? And do you regiser / unregister yours broadcastreceiver in `onResume` / `onPause`?

Comment: yes I edited my question and added, yes the reference of the imageview is imageBattery

Comment: Hmm, do you construct Your ImageView from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html ?

Comment: Well in the XML when I declare the ImageView I add android:src to it you can check it I just re-edit my question again :D

Comment: Ant those items are nested in  `<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`
?

Comment: yes you can check <level-list> I posted on my Question (edited)

Comment: Maybe you can put on `Log` value of `percent` variable? The other possibility is that this value doesn't get changed...

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in images

`LevelListDrawable` doesn't *append* new image when level changed, it just shows the image for level you've set

try differen images and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Ok I'll try but I could not see why the images be the problem!

Answer (score 0):

try this in your onCreate:

```
    imageBattery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageBatery);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        imageBattery.setImageLevel(i * 10);
    }
```

is smth changed ?

Comment: did you try it with different images of different width?